# Help to understand why VLQ declined?

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100295/changing-the-open-atrium-2-login-hyperlink/100756#100756) / [revision](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/100756/3) as very low quality, but it was declined, I just want to know is this not low quality ?

Comment: Related MSO question: [When to use the flag “low quality”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216107/225745)

Comment: Little side-note.  Normally, mods will mark flags as helpful when they are done in good faith even if we don't do something about them.  However, marking a VLQ as helpful will carry a downvote from Community.  So, I am very picky when handling these.  The custom decline reason on this was "VLQ should be for things that can be deleted. This can be cleaned up with some edits."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This post is not a VLQ now. Revision 3 happened before moderator came to see it, and it wasn't VLQ. It needed some editing, but was a substantial answer that made sense.

2nd revision was, indeed, very low quality, but it also looks like accidental save before user finished writing - this happens, and usually is fixed when user realizes it happened.

Flagging posts that are less than an hour old is risky - probably author hangs around and it is possible he will fix it before flag is evaluated, as he should. It means you could have make him to fix it faster if you commented instead of flagging. And you should not flag if you can resolve issue without flag. This time it was possible, so flag was correctly declined.

Answer (score 4):

It was not a *very low quality* post because it just needed an edit. The meaning of the post was clear, and it was possible to edit it to put it into shape.
VLQ flags should be reserved for very sloppy posts that are not salvageable with editing. As this was not the case, the flag was correctly (IMO) handled.

Comment: Yup.  It looks like the third revision was what was current when the answer was flagged.  That just needed some cleanup, which I did.